# How to make a dropdown menu in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu in my Blazor app. It is declared in my `Header.razor` as shown below:

```
    <div class="header-sign">
        <div class="dropdown" id="toggleDropdown">
            <button class="button-md" type="button">
                <i data-feather="user"></i>
                <span>Personal cab</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a class="dropdown-link" href="">
                        <p class="text-md">Cabinet</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a class="dropdown-link" href="">
                        <p class="text-md">Sign out</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The dropdown can be triggered via JS script like this:

```
$("#toggleDropdown").on("mouseenter", () => {
$(this).find(".dropdown-list").addClass("is-active");
});
```

I have my header declared in `MainLayout.razor` like shown below:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<Header></Header>

<main class="main">
    @Body
</main>

<Footer></Footer>
```

And this approach doesn't work.

Everything changes if I replace the above-mentioned `Header.razor` with razor page `Header.cshtml` with exactly the same markup and render it in `_Layout.cshtml` in such a way:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Header")
```

Looks like the above markup can only work in `*.cshtml` files but cannot in `*.razor` and I don't quiet understand the reason. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: You are correct,  Blazor does not allow any JavaScript inside a .razor page.

Comment: @Yogi yeah, thanks. So what should I do? Some custom implementation of a dropdown as a Blazor component?

Comment: why do you need js for this? why don't you use @onclick event handler and have a variable that holds the value based on the click state

Comment: @MohammedAlwedaei because I want it to work on mouse enter and not on click

Comment: you can use @onmouseover as an alternative. but from a user experience perspective, it wouldn't be nice to use mouseenter for dropdown items. Just like Bootstrap shifted from hover to click for dropdowns

Comment: How does one hover on a touchscreen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Huge thanks to Mohammed Alwedaei, I figured out how to solve my question. His remark that the dropdown should be activated on a click and not on a hover really solved it to me.

We should just keep state of a dropdown list and toggle classes of it in a bit tricky way (with a ternary operator `@(isActive ? "is-active" : "")`). To make the dropdown work as intended, we should define `@onclick` attribute and also `@onblur` to disable it when user clicks somewhere else.

The code below works just fine:

```
<div class="header-sign">
    <div class="dropdown" id="toggleDropdown">
        <button @onclick="Show" @onblur="Hide" class="button-md" type="button">
            <i data-feather="user"></i>
            <span>Personal cab</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-list @(isActive ? "is-active" : "")">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a class="dropdown-link" href="/cabinet">
                    <p class="text-md">Cabinet</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
                <a @onclick="LogOutAsync" class="dropdown-link" href="">
                    <p class="text-md">LogOut</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool isActive = false;

    private void Show()
    {
        isActive = true;
    }

    private void Hide()
    {
        isActive = false;
    }

    private async Task LogOutAsync()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Not work in Blazor Web App (Auto - SERVER & WASM) mode (.Net 8 rc2)

Comment: @مهدی that's strange, only basics of C# are used here. Did you test it on another platform (for example .NET 6/7)? Maybe the reason is in your CSS.

Comment: There are a few gotchas that makes it harder as I understand it, hiding the menu when someone clicks outside for instance (onBlur is only within the scope of the button).

Comment: In terms of .NET8, am only re-working my code now and a few gotchas with the rendering mode and placement of the files. 

@مهدی Are you placing this in the client project?