# How to show/hide dropdown menu on Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to use [this dropdown menu code](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/elements/dropdowns) from tailwindcss. I can hide the dropdown and show it on button press using the following code.

```cs
@if (menuOpen)
{
    ....
}

@code {
    bool menuOpen;

    void ToggleMenu()
    {
        menuOpen = !menuOpen;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

How to close the dropdown menu when the user clicks on something else on the site?

I tried to use `onblur` event but that prevents me from clicking on the menu items in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156540/it-possible-to-click-outside-an-element-to-close-it-on-blazor/70161538#70161538

Comment: I'm trying to implement a working drop down menu in Blazor, and onblur is about the only thing that currently works for me. I've been following this answer to another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165072/142914